# how can I iclude an inner list in a RowMapper class

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a question about Spring JDBC RowMapper organization.

Let's say I have a table `a` with fields `id` and `name`, table `a_b` and table `b`.

```
a
id integer
name character varying (16)

b
id integer
name character varying (16)

a_b
a_b_id integer
aid integer
bid integer
```

The Class structure is not so symmetrical:

```
class A{
int id;
String name;
List<B> bs;
}

class B{
int id;
String name;
}
```

I want to construct a RowMapper class for a class A. The start code looks like:

```
class AMapper implements RowMapper<A>{
     public A mapRow(ResultSet rs, int num){
        A a = new A();
        a.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        a.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        return a;
     }
}
```

How can I also map the list of `b`s? Is there any way to get it without in-mapper sql query?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727099/mapping-relational-db-to-a-listobject-each-containing-a-listobject-using-jdb/25727905#25727905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get them with a single query, you'll have to use JOINs to fetch from multiple tables(whether you use LEFT join or INNER it depends on what you want to achieve) which will return you a matrix of combined columns, something like this in ResultSet:

```
a_id | a_name | b_id | b_name | ...
------------------------------------
  1  | Name1A |  1   | Name1B | ...
  1  | Name1A |  2   | Name2B | ...
  1  | Name1A |  3   | Name3B | ...
```

Although you have 1 A record, it is associated with multiple B's and will be in every row.

You need to track A's in via Map or Set. Something like this(you may need to tweak it):

```
class AMapper implements RowMapper<A> {
    Map<Integer, A> aMap = new HashMap<>();

    public A mapRow(ResultSet rs, int num){
        A a = aMap.get(rs.getInt("id"));
        if(a == null){
           a = new A();
           a.setId(rs.getInt("a_id"));
           a.setName(rs.getString("a_name"));
           aMap.put(a.getId(), a);
        }
        B b = new B();
        b.setId(rs.getInt("b_id");
        b.setName(rs.getString("b_name"));
        a.addB(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi isah! Unfortunatelly it seems not to work for queryForObject

Comment: What's the problem? The code I suggested does not have anything to do with `queryForObject` apart from being a valid RowMapper implementation which `queryForObject` accepts.

Comment: It's actually ok. but the result row set (before the rowmapper starts mapping) does not contain only one row (in the case, for example a_id =1, bid = 1 and a_id = 1 and bid = 2) and the query for object throws exception. So, queryFor object accepts such an implementation as argument but does not work with it.